# How to conduct power profile in Android with given functions in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm recently researching about power consumption of android devices (Specifically, Pixel 7 Pro).

I found that the power profiler that google provides in the recent android studio fits for my purpose (https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/power-profiler), so I've tried to use it but I can't find way or experiences to use it.

If one can use this function, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

I tried to use https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/power-profiler, but failed. I can't find such function in android studio hedgehog.

Answer (score 0):

You now need to

- go into "Profiler"
- start a session with the "+" button
- click the CPU graph
- Select "System trace" and record a system trace

The energy consumption data appears at the end of the report

[image: battery consumption in Android Studio system trace report]